# java user input check palindrome and print out counting

Tags: java, palindrome

I have a user input like this: 
banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james, joyce

2 questions for this: 
first, I would like to print with the whole line of user input. System.out.println("There are " + total + " words in " + banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james, joyce);
Second, I was not able to print the last line. Please lecture me, thanks.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    palindromeCheck();                      // test your method
}
// Part 3
/**
 * This program reads words, identifies, counts and writes all the palindromes and the total
 * palindrome count.
 */
public static void palindromeCheck(){

    // you could use any of the words below to test your method:
    // banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james, joyce

    String someWord = ""; // Stores words read from user input
    int count = 0;        // keeps track of Palindrome words only (define algorithm to count # of palindrome words
    int total = 0;        // Counts the total number of lines read from the given text file

    System.out.println(" Enter some words separated by white space");    // Ask for user input

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // hint 1: Using keybord.next() will only return what comes before a space.
    // hint 2: Using keybord.nextLine() automatically reads the entire current line.
           // store each word in a string variable and then do your operations

    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
        String temp = keyboard.next();
        total++;

        int Len = temp.length();

        for(int i=0 ; i < (Len/2) ; i++) {
            //debug: System.out.println("first word "+temp.charAt(i)+"  second word "+temp.charAt(Len-1-i));
            if(temp.charAt(i)== temp.charAt(Len-1-i))count++;
        }
        someWord += temp;
        System.out.println("There are " + total + " words in " + someWord);   // test
    }

    System.out.println("There are "+count +" palindromes out of "+total+" words.");

    keyboard.close();

    // x is a variable for count and y is variable total
    // #2. print “There are x palindromes out of y words”
    System.out.println("There are "+count +" palindromes out of "+total+" words.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #1 change the variable `someWords` to a `List<String>` and for question #2 you should use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. Your last line was never printing because the `while` loop was never exiting.

See the updated `palindromeCheck` method below:

***Code***

/**
     * This program reads words, identifies, counts and writes all the palindromes and the total
     * palindrome count.
     */
    public static void palindromeCheck() {

```
    // you could use any of the words below to test your method:
    // banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james, joyce

    List<String> someWords = new ArrayList<>(); // Stores words read from user input
    int count = 0;        // keeps track of Palindrome words only (define algorithm to count # of palindrome words
    int total = 0;        // Counts the total number of lines read from the given text file

    System.out.println(" Enter some words separated by white space");    // Ask for user input

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // hint 1: Using keybord.next() will only return what comes before a space.
    // hint 2: Using keybord.nextLine() automaticatlly reads the enire current line.
    // store each word in a string variable and then do your operations

    for (String word : keyboard.nextLine().split(" ")) {
        int length = word.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++) {
            //debug: System.out.println("first word "+temp.charAt(i)+"  second word "+temp.charAt(Len-1-i));
            if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(length - 1 - i)) count++;
        }
        someWords.add(word);
        System.out.println("There are " + someWords.size() + " words in " + someWords);   // test
    }

    System.out.println("There are " + count + " palindromes out of " + total + " words.");

    keyboard.close();

    // x is a variable for count and y is variable total
    // #2. print “There are x palindromes out of y words”
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " palindromes out of " + total + " words.");
}
```

***Output***

```
Enter some words separated by white space
banana sneeze radar roof kayak mine racer racecar refer james joyce
There are 1 words in [banana]
There are 2 words in [banana, sneeze]
There are 3 words in [banana, sneeze, radar]
There are 4 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof]
There are 5 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak]
There are 6 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine]
There are 7 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer]
There are 8 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar]
There are 9 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer]
There are 10 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james]
There are 11 words in [banana, sneeze, radar, roof, kayak, mine, racer, racecar, refer, james, joyce]
There are 12 palindromes out of 0 words.
There are 12 palindromes out of 0 words.
```

Just to note there is some issue with your logic to check if a word is a palindrome or not.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way to do it without list<string>, because my professor has not lectured array yet.